# How do I use GCC on El Capitan?

Tags: gcc

I installed gcc via homebrew with no errors.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49
brew unlink gcc49 && brew link gcc49
```

But when I try to run gcc, clang is used instead.

```
~$:gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Edit:

```
~$:type gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
~$:type /usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
~$:echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of invoking using `gcc` you need to call `gcc-4.9`. Alternately you could create an alias for `gcc` to point to `gcc-4.9`(although that is risky).

Comment: Would generally advice against the alias. It can cause no end of trouble if you're trying to use Xcode or something that expects and standard Apple dev environment with `clang` as the `gcc` complier and you've got an alias like that.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who stumbles upon this currently (like I did), I found that I needed to locate my version of `gcc` (which I had installed with `brew`). This is annoying when `gcc --version` gives the `clang` version instead! To find the correct `gcc` version, run

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin | grep gcc
gcc-10
gcc-ar-10
gcc-nm-10
...
```

So I had `gcc-10`. Whenever you wish to use `gcc` just replace it with `gcc-10`, e.g. `man gcc-10`. Of course you could write an alias for `gcc` to `gcc-10`, but this probably is not a great idea as Xcode seems to rely on the `gcc --> clang` simlink.